# Client-side validation doesn't work in asp.net mvc 1 with "if" condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I asked this question before, but I decided to be more specific, so maybe somebody could help.

My question is about this particular problem:

In the ASP.NET MVC app. I have a check box, "Food/Bev", which is of a boolean type,  and i have a "Select" list on the Form, and I'd like to know how to manage this:

If the check box is checked:

- A dropdown list "Caterer" becomes a required field.
- A request cannot be submitted unless the Caterer option is
  selected from the list.

If the check box is not checked:

- The Caterer dropdown list is not a required field.

And vice virsa.

- If both fields are empty, then these fields are not required.

In the Model I have this code:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Caterer)
                && (FoodBeverage == true))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Caterer", "Caterer is a required field");
```

In a View I put this code:
For the "select" field "Caterer":

```
<label for="Caterer">Caterer</label>
                    <% if (Model.Request.Caterer == null && Model.Request.FoodBeverage !=null) %>
                    <select name="Caterer", "required">
               <option>A</option>
               <option>B</option>
               <option>C</option>
```

For the "checkbox" field "Food/Bev":

```
<% if (!Model.Request.FoodBeverage && Model.Request.Caterer == null) %>         
                    <%= Html.CheckBox("FoodBeverage", Model.Request.FoodBeverage, new { @class = "required" })%>  
                    <%= Html.ValidationMessage("FoodBeverage", "*")%>
```

The problem is that the system treats these fields as "required" in both scenarios: if they are both "null" and in the case if one  of them is selected or checked.

Looks like the "if" condition on the form doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is simply that the If logic isn't validated by the ValidateInput attribute; assuming you're using that of course.

Because MVC1 doesn't do client side validation, this is probably one of the cases where you can implement it, for your very specific requirement.

Add a Javascript Submit function to your form submit, and then you can check the state of the checkbox and that the select list has a valid selection, and simply return false if it's not.

If you check the output code as it stands, you can find the CSS class names the validation logic puts on, so you can emulate the same behavior.

Also, I know this isn't a solution, but if you can upgrade to a later version of MVC I would try it, the unobstrusive ClientSide validation in MVC3 is far superior and anything that can avoid a server round-trip in my book is good.

Comment: I was thinking about upgrading MVC 1 to at least MVC 2, but I inherited this project, and I'm not sure that the upgrade is a good idea at this point. Is it possible to overcome this validation problem as i need it to be with any available validation plugin that work with mvc 1? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know about MVC1 plugins; I do know there are a couple of utilities that can convert from earlier versions to MVC3 but that's clearly a different question altogether.  The Javascript method I suggested in my answer would definitely work though.